# holomorphic fiber space when fibers are of general type

Tags: minimal-model-program

Let $\pi:X\to S$ be a holomorphic fibre space, then from birational geometry, the canonical divisor of general fibers are ample or trivial. When fibers are of general type?

Answer (score 1):

This is just Abundance conjecture. In fact if $X$ be minimal model variety (i.e Proj of canonical ring $R(X,K_X)$)then there exists a fibration $X\to B$ such that the genera fibres $X_b$ are of general type and there exists an ample divisor $H$ such that $mK_X=\pi^*(H)$

. Note that if you have a fibration which base and general fibers are of general type then total space must be of general type

Comment: if $mK_X=\pi^*(H)$ then by adjuction the canonical bundle of a generic fiber $X_b$ is torsion, not ample.